# Using scaled resolution in Macbook Pro Retina can cause overheating?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, performance, resolution

I'm using a late 2014 13 inch macbook pro retina. I'm using a scaled resolution of 1680*1050. When using this resolution, i don't know why, my laptop gets overheated. How can i fix it?

Comment: Why would you run in that resolution in the first place? :) Because you are gaming or?

Comment: Running in a non-native resolution causes extra work for the GPU, which in turn causes extra heat to be generated. When you say it is "overheating", is it shutting itself down due or exhibiting other software symptoms due to extreme temperature, or is it simply that is becoming very hot to the touch?

Comment: @JW_ On normal use like browsing.